# Copy lots of table records from SQL Server Dev to Prod

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with about 5 million records and I only need to move the last 1 million to production (as the other 4 million are there). What is the best way to do this so I don't have to recopy the entire table each time?

Comment: Is this on the same machine, same sql instance or same db? (or which of these are different from source to target?)

Comment: they are on completely different servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little faster will probably be:

```
Insert into prod.dbo.table (column1, column2....)
Select column1, column2.... from dev.dbo.table d
where not exists (
    select 1 from prod.dbo.table pc where pc.pkey = d.pkey
    )
```

But you need to tell us if these tables are on the same server or not

Also how frequently is this run and how robust does it need to be? There are alternative solutions depending on your requirements.

Given this late arriving gem from the OP: *no need to compare as I know the IDs > X* , then you do not have to do an expensive comparison. You can just use

```
Insert into prod.dbo.table (column1, column2....)
Select column1, column2.... from dev.dbo.table d
where ID > x
```

This will be far more efficient as you are only transferring the rows you need.

Comment: they are on the separate server

Comment: Ooops. Got that wrong. But still, MERGE would work, wouldn't it? I guess it's as slow as the other solutions though. DTS is also an option. This is quite fast and as far as I remember, DTS has an option to only insert new records.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: (Sorry for revising so much.  I'm understanding your question better now)

```
Insert into TblProd
     Select * from TblDev where 
     pkey not in (select pkey from tblprod)
```

This should only copy over records that aren't already in your target table.

Answer (score 2):

Since they are on a separate server that changes everything. In short: in order to know what *isn't* in dev you need to compare everything in DEV to everything in PROD anyway, so there is no simple way to avoid comparing huge datasets.

Some different strategies used for replication between PROD and DEV systems:

A. Backup and restore the whole database across and apply scripts afterwards to clean it up

B. Implement triggers in the PROD database that record the changes then copy only changed records accross

C. Identify some kind of partition or set of records that you *know* don't change (i.e. 12 months ago), and only refresh those  that aren't in that dataset.

D. Copy ALL of prod into a staging table on the DEV server using SSIS. Use a very similar query to above to only insert new records across the database. Delete the staging table.

E. You might be able to find a third party SSIS component that does this efficiently. Out of the box, SSIS is inefficient at comparative updates.

Do you actually have an idea of what those last million records are? i.e. are the for a location or a date or something? Can you write a select to identify them?

Based on this comment:

*no need to compare as I know the IDs > X will work*

You can run this on the DEV server, assuming you have created a linked server called PRODSERVER on the DEV server

```
INSERT INTO DB.dbo.YOURTABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3...)
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3...
FROM PRODSERVER.DB.dbo.YOURTABLE
WHERE ID > X
```

Look up 'SQL Server Linked Servers' for more information on how to create one.

This is fine for a one off but if you do this regularly you might want to make something more robust.

For example you could create a script that exports the data using BCP.EXE to a file, copies it across to DEV and imports it again. This is more reliable as it does it in one batch rather than requiring a network connection the whole time.

Comment: if they are in Sql Management studio can't I refer to thme as devservername.databasename.dbo.table and the same with production?

Comment: Yes you can do that if you have a linked server defined. But if you perform a join or use an IN over a linked server it drags all of the data across the network. For example if you are comparing tables to find whats different it will drag 5 million records locally to compare them. Your db and network admins won't like you. Can you write a select statement in PROD to identify the different records, or do you need to compare primary keys to find them?

Comment: if one of my connections is by IP address, can I still link to it? (+1 for your help)

Comment: Yes. You can create a linked server to an IP Address. But it still suffers from the same problem.

Comment: Based on your comment I have edited my answer. Please note it saves everyone a lot of time if you provide all information (such as this) up front.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are on the same server, you can do something like this

I am using MySQL, so may be the syntax will be a little bit different, but in my opinion everything should be the same.

```
INSERT INTO newTable (columnsYouWantToCopy)
    SELECT columnsYouWantToCopy
    FROM oldTable WHERE clauseWhichGivesYouOnlyRecodsYouNeed
```

If on another server, you can do something like this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: its sql server 2005 not mysql